# using StackedLayout class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am testing how to use the `StackedLayout` to make layouts on the screen change when particular buttons are pressed.

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QComboBox>

class Test: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QPushButton *button1, *button2;
    QWidget *parentWidget1, *parentWidget2;
    QLabel *label1, *label2;
    QHBoxLayout *layout1, *layout2;
    QStackedLayout *stackedLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout;

private slots:
    void layout1_h();
    void layout2_h();

public:
    Test(QWidget* parent=0);

};


#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

void Test::layout1_h()
{
    stackedLayout->setCurrentIndex(0);
    //window->show();
}

void Test::layout2_h()
{
    stackedLayout->setCurrentIndex(1);
    //window->show();
}



Test::Test(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    //widget = new QWidget;
    stackedLayout = new QStackedLayout;
    parentWidget1 = new QWidget;
    parentWidget2 = new QWidget;
    button1 = new QPushButton("change1");
    button2 = new QPushButton("change2");
    label1 = new QLabel("hello1");
    label2 = new QLabel("hello2");
    layout1 = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout2 = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout1->addWidget(label1);
    layout1->addWidget(button1);
    layout1->addWidget(button2);

    layout2->addWidget(label2);
    layout2->addWidget(button1);
    layout2->addWidget(button2);

    parentWidget1->setLayout(layout1);
    parentWidget2->setLayout(layout2);
    stackedLayout->addWidget(parentWidget1);
    stackedLayout->addWidget(parentWidget2);
    stackedLayout->setCurrentIndex(0);
    mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(stackedLayout);

    connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(layout1_h()));
    connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(layout2_h()));

    setLayout(mainLayout);
    //window.show();

}
```

So I have the application up and running but for some reason, the buttons are not displayed. What's wrong??

Comment: Did you set the current tab for the stacked layout (`stackedLayout->setCurrentIndex(0)` )? Why don't you use Qt Designer (comes integrated with Qt Creator or standalone) for composing your UI?

Comment: @Violet Girraffe :I did that now. But the result is same.(Look at the edited code).I will use the Qt creator but as for now I want to get some feel of Qt programming.

Comment: `mainLayout` seems unnecessary, throw it away and just do: `setCentralWidget(stackedLayout);`
But then again, let designer do the dirty work. Don't create layouts by hand.

Comment: I can't do setCentralWidget becuase QWidget class is the parent. setCentralWidget is when QMainWindow is the parent class of my application. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button1 and button2 cannot be in both layouts simultaneously. The layout2 became manager of two buttons and parentWidget2 became owner of them.

Comment: Aha! Nice observaation. Thanks!